# Go channel infinite loop

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to catch errors from a group of goroutines using a channel, but the channel enters an infinite loop, starts consuming CPU.

```
func UnzipFile(f *bytes.Buffer, location string) error {
    zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(f.Bytes()), int64(f.Len()))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := os.MkdirAll(location, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    errorChannel := make(chan error)
    errorList := []error{}

    go errorChannelWatch(errorChannel, errorList)

    fileWaitGroup := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for _, file := range zipReader.File {
        fileWaitGroup.Add(1)
        go writeZipFileToLocal(file, location, errorChannel, fileWaitGroup)
    }

    fileWaitGroup.Wait()

    close(errorChannel)

    log.Println(errorList)

    return nil
}

func errorChannelWatch(ch chan error, list []error) {
    for {
        select {
        case err := <- ch:

            list = append(list, err)
        }
    }
}

func writeZipFileToLocal(file *zip.File, location string, ch chan error, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    zipFilehandle, err := file.Open()

    if err != nil {
        ch <- err
        return
    }

    defer zipFilehandle.Close()

    if file.FileInfo().IsDir() {
        if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Join(location, file.Name), os.ModePerm); err != nil {
            ch <- err
        }
        return
    }

    localFileHandle, err := os.OpenFile(filepath.Join(location, file.Name), os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, file.Mode())

    if err != nil {
        ch <- err
        return
    }

    defer localFileHandle.Close()

    if _, err := io.Copy(localFileHandle, zipFilehandle); err != nil {
        ch <- err
        return
    }

    ch <- fmt.Errorf("Test error")
}
```

So I am looping a slice of files and writing them to my disk, when there is an error I report back to the `errorChannel` to save that error into a slice.

I use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for all goroutines and when they are done I want to print `errorList` and check if there was any error during the execution.

The list is always empty, even if I add `ch <- fmt.Errorf("test")` at the end of `writeZipFileToLocal` and the channel always hangs up.

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. For the first point, the infinite loop:**

Citing from [golang language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator):

> A receive operation on a closed channel can always proceed
>   immediately, yielding the element type's zero value after any
>   previously sent values have been received.

So in this function

```
func errorChannelWatch(ch chan error, list []error) {
    for {
        select {
        case err := <- ch:

            list = append(list, err)
        }
    }
}
```

after ch gets closed this turns into an infinite loop adding `nil` values to `list`.

Try this instead:

```
func errorChannelWatch(ch chan error, list []error) {
    for err := range ch {
            list = append(list, err)
    }
}
```

**2. For the second point, why you don't see anything in your error list:**

The problem is this call:

```
errorChannel := make(chan error)
errorList := []error{}

go errorChannelWatch(errorChannel, errorList)
```

Here you hand `errorChannelWatch` the `errorList` as a value. So the slice `errorList` will not be changed by the function. What is changed, is the underlying array, as long as the `append` calls don't need to allocate a new one.

To remedy the situation, either hand a slice pointer to `errorChannelWatch` or rewrite it as a call to a closure, capturing
`errorList`.

For the first proposed solution, change `errorChannelWatch` to

```
func errorChannelWatch(ch chan error, list *[]error) {
    for err := range ch {
            *list = append(*list, err)
    }
}
```

and the call to

```
errorChannel := make(chan error)
errorList := []error{}

go errorChannelWatch(errorChannel, &errorList)
```

For the second proposed solution, just change the call to

```
   errorChannel := make(chan error)
   errorList := []error{}

   go func() {
      for err := range errorChannel {
          errorList = append(errorList, err)
      }
   } ()
```

**3. A minor remark:**

One could think, that there is a synchronisation problem here:

```
fileWaitGroup.Wait()

close(errorChannel)

log.Println(errorList)
```

How can you be sure, that errorList isn't modified, after the call to close? One could reason, that you can't know, how many values the goroutine `errorChannelWatch` still has to process.

Your synchronisation seems correct to me, as you do the `wg.Done()`
after the send to the error channel and so all error values will
be sent, when `fileWaitGroup.Wait()` returns.

But that can change, if someone later adds a buffering to the error
channel or alters the code.

So I would advise to at least explain the synchronisation in a comment.